# Как загрузить png-изображения через GDI+?

Tags: windows, gdi+, c, c++, graphics

Как загрузить изображение (png) в окно (хэндл) через GDI+?

Answer (score 2):

```
// name - имя ресурса
// type - тип ресурса
// instance - модуль

if (HRSRC resource = ::FindResource(instance, name, type))
    if (DWORD size = ::SizeofResource(instance, resource))
        if (const void* data = ::LockResource(::LoadResource(instance, resource)))
            if (HGLOBAL handle  = ::GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, size)) {
                if (void* buffer = ::GlobalLock(handle)) {
                    CopyMemory(buffer, data, size);

                    IStream* stream = NULL;
                    if (::CreateStreamOnHGlobal(handle, FALSE, &stream) == S_OK)
                    {
                        if (Gdiplus::Bitmap* bitmap = 
                            Gdiplus::Bitmap::FromStream(stream))
                        { 
                            if (bitmap->GetLastStatus() == Gdiplus::Ok) {
                                // А вот здесь идет работа с изображением
                            }

                            delete bitmap;
                        }
                        stream->Release();
                    }
                    ::GlobalUnlock(handle);
                }
                ::GlobalFree(handle);
            }
```