# Как загрузить картинку из памяти С++ (Win)?

Tags: c++, bitmap, ole

Есть пример загрузки картинки из файла (проверено, загружает bmp, jpg, gif и др.). Как можно загрузить `HBIТMAP` из памяти?

Для ф-ции **OleCreateFromData** не могу понять как создать `IDataObject` из куска (думаю именно она является ответом). Есть на SO пример с GdiPlus, но там не понятно как перевести его в HBITMAP. `LoadBitmapIndirect` - загружает только bitmap определённой конфигурации (не подходит). `OleCreateFromFile` - загружает с файла - не подходит.

Есть ещё, можно создать объект через `CoCreateInstance`, и через `IPersistStream` загрузить `IStorage`. Тут странная проблема в **borand delphi** есть [кусок кода](ftp://osu-tulsa.okstate.edu/Delen/VS.NET/CD1/Program%20Files/Microsoft%20Visual%20Studio%20.NET%202003/Vc7/atlmfc/src/mfc/olecli1.cpp), но почему то он даёт ошибку:

```
char[] gif={0x47,0x49,0x46,0x38,0x39,0x61,0x0C,0x00,0x0C,0x00,0x80,0xFF,0x00,0x9C,0x00,0x00
,0xC0,0xC0,0xC0,0x21,0xF9,0x04,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x01,0x00,0x2C,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00
    ,0x0C,0x00,0x0C,0x00,0x00,0x02,0x1B,0x8C,0x7F,0x80,0xA1,0x09,0xCD,0x9E,0x79,0x72
,0xD2,0xBB,0x6E,0xCD,0x74,0x59,0x8C,0x68,0xDD,0xA7,0x68,0xD1,0x06,0x6E,0x96,0xC7,0x06,0x05,0x00,0x3B};
int dwBytes = sizeof(gif);
HGLOBAL hStorage = ::GlobalAlloc(GMEM_SHARE|GMEM_MOVEABLE, dwBytes);
    if (hStorage == NULL)           AfxThrowMemoryException();    
    LPVOID lpBuf = ::GlobalLock(hStorage); ASSERT(lpBuf != NULL);
    memcpy(lpBuf,gif, dwBytes);
    ::GlobalUnlock(hStorage);    
    // throw exception in case of partial object
    SCODE sc = CreateILockBytesOnHGlobal(hStorage, TRUE, &m_lpLockBytes);
    if (sc != S_OK){::GlobalFree(hStorage);AfxThrowOleException(sc);}
    sc = ::StgOpenStorageOnILockBytes(m_lpLockBytes, NULL,
        STGM_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE|STGM_READWRITE, NULL, 0, &m_lpStorage);
```

`StgOpenStorageOnILockBytes` даёт либо ошибку 800300FB (*invalid header*), либо 800300FF (*invalid flag*), либо 0x80030050 (*file not exist*). Ошибка зависит от флагов. Можно ли как-то по другому в объект `CLSID_Picture_DIB` загрузить картинку?

Вот пример того, как можно загрузить из файла (он грузит gif, т.е. OLE всё-таки умеет грузить картинки):

```
HANDLE Handle;

// Загрузка в Handle битмапа
HRESULT LoadOLE(wchar_t* FileName){      
  HRESULT Result;
  tagFORMATETC fmt;
  tagSTGMEDIUM stg;
  ILockBytes *FLockBytes=0;
  IStorage *iStorage=0;
  IDataObject *Data=0;
  if ((Result =CreateILockBytesOnHGlobal(0, 1, &FLockBytes))!=0) return Result;
  if ((Result =StgCreateDocfileOnILockBytes(FLockBytes, STGM_READWRITE
    | STGM_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE | STGM_CREATE, 0, &iStorage))!=0){
      FLockBytes->Release();
      FLockBytes=0;
      return Result;
      };
  fmt.cfFormat = CF_BITMAP;
  fmt.dwAspect=1;
  fmt.lindex=-1;
  fmt.ptd=0;
  fmt.tymed=2;
  Result =OleCreateFromFile(CLSID_Picture_Dib,FileName,
   IID_IDataObject,OLERENDER_NONE,&fmt,0,iStorage,(void**)&Data);
  if (Result==0) Result =OleRun(Data);
  if (Result==0) Result =Data->GetData(&fmt,&stg);
  if (Result==0) Handle = stg.hBitmap;
  if (Data) Data->Release();       Data=0;
  iStorage->Release();   iStorage=0;
  FLockBytes->Release(); FLockBytes=0;
 // return Result;    
// Отрисовка Handle битмапа
HDC dest = GetDC(0 /*Дескриптор окна*/); // допустим монитор
HDC dc =  CreateCompatibleDC(0);
SelectObject(dc,Handle);
BitBlt(dest,x,y,xx,yy, dc,0,0,SRCCOPY);  
ReleaseDC( 0 /*Дескриптор окна*/, dest);
}
```

Но вопрос остаётся открытым.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Получилось таки через GDIPlus, может не лучший способ, но результат есть. Написан на borland, без подключения лишних библиотек (кроме загрузки gdiplus.dll). Gif загрузил. Но если будет ответ через OLE буду рад.

```
HBITMAP LoadBitmapGDI(char* data, int size) {
  HANDLE m = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_FIXED,size);
  DWORD sz;
  ReadProcessMemory(GetCurrentProcess(),data, m,size,&sz);
  IStream * stm = 0;
  if ( CreateStreamOnHGlobal(m,0,&stm) != 0 ) {
      GlobalFree(m);
      return 0;
      }
  HANDLE g = LoadLibraryA("gdiplus.dll");
  int __stdcall (*GdiplusStartup)(void*,void*);
  int __stdcall (*GdiplusShutdown)();
  int __stdcall (*GdipCreateBitmapFromStream)(IStream* stream, void** nativebitmap);
  int __stdcall (*GdipCreateHBITMAPFromBitmap)(void* nativebitmap, void** bitmap, int argbBackground);
  int __stdcall (*GdipDisposeImage)(void* h);
  (void*)GdiplusStartup=GetProcAddress(g,"GdiplusStartup");
  (void*)GdiplusShutdown=GetProcAddress(g,"GdiplusShutdown");
  (void*)GdipCreateBitmapFromStream  =GetProcAddress(g,"GdipCreateBitmapFromStream");
  (void*)GdipCreateHBITMAPFromBitmap  = GetProcAddress(g,"GdipCreateHBITMAPFromBitmap");
  (void*)GdipDisposeImage  = GetProcAddress(g,"GdipDisposeImage");   
  HANDLE h = 0;
  HBITMAP bm = 0;
  char st[256] = { 1, 0,};
  HANDLE st2 = 0;
  GdiplusStartup(&st2,&st);    
  GdipCreateBitmapFromStream(stm,&h);
  GdipCreateHBITMAPFromBitmap(h,&bm,0 /*color !*/);
  GdipDisposeImage(h);
  GdiplusShutdown();
  FreeLibrary(g);
  GlobalFree(m);
  stm->Release();
  stm = 0; 
  return bm;
 }
 -----------------------------------------test
char[]   gif={0x47,0x49,0x46,0x38,0x39,0x61,0x0C,0x00,0x0C,0x00,0x80,0xFF,0x00,0x9C,0x00,0x00
,0xC0,0xC0,0xC0,0x21,0xF9,0x04,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x01,0x00,0x2C,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00
    ,0x0C,0x00,0x0C,0x00,0x00,0x02,0x1B,0x8C,0x7F,0x80,0xA1,0x09,0xCD,0x9E,0x79,0x72
,0xD2,0xBB,0x6E,0xCD,0x74,0x59,0x8C,0x68,0xDD,0xA7,0x68,0xD1,0x06,0x6E,0x96,0xC7,0x06,0x05,0x00,0x3B};
HBITMAP h =  LoadBitmapGDI(gif,sizeof(gif));
```

Вот ещё примеры

[пример1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/30301/17974) довольно простой

которые грузят перечисленые форматы.