# Как заменить StretchDIBits на BitBlt

Tags: c++, winapi

Здравствуйте! Использую такую функцию:

```
StretchDIBits(deviceContext, 0, 0, buffer->Width, buffer->Height, 0, 0, buffer->Width, buffer->Height, buffer->Memory, &buffer->Info, DIB_RGB_COLORS, SRCCOPY);
```

Но она медленная по сравнению с BitBlt. Вопрос в том, как ее заменить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

это делается проще всего где-то так:

```
// Создаём bitmap контекст
HBITMAP bm = CreateBitmap( buffer->Width,  buffer->Height, 1/*planes*/, buffer->Info.bmiHeader.biBitCount,  buffer->Memory);
HDC bmDC = CreateCompatibleDC(0);
SelectObject(bmDC,bm);
// Теперь можно рендерить
BitBlt(deviceContext, 0/*x*/,0/*y*/, buffer->Width,  buffer->Height, bmDC, 0,0, SRCCOPY);
// Что б не было утечки памяти, когда картинка не нужна - надо освободить память
DeleteDC(bmDC);
DeleteObject(bm);
```

Для работы с памятью на прямую, вам нужна таки секция:

```
void ** bits = null; 
HDC bmDC = CreateCompatibleDC(0);
HBITMAP bm = CreateDIBSection(bmDC,buffer->Info,DIB_RGB_COLORS,&bits,0,0);
SelectObject(bmDC,bm);
```

За тем вам нужно скопировать данные именно в выданый системой участок памяти и именно с bits работать. эту ссылку *bits* можно после копирования переписать в buffer->Memory https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/dd183494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx Освобождать (DeleteObject,DeleteDC) и рисовать (BitBlt) также само.

Рисовать win умеет только dc. Но эта dc должна быть связана с bitmap. Поэтому так.

Проверьте что б CreateBitmap возвращало не ноль. Ф-ция довольно "вредная". Она не все форматы поддерживает. Формат указывается в предпоследнем параметре. Ещё я сталкивался с тем, что строки картинки в некоторых случаях нужно выравнивать по границам двойного слова, иначе картинку "перекашивает" по диагонали набок.

Если надо загружать с памяти или с диска то можно так: [Как загрузить картинку из памяти С++ (Win)?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/556781/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%A1-win)

Comment: У меня в цикле отрисовывает BitBlt, надо постоянно Bitmap и HDC создавать или можно 1 раз создать и все

Comment: И ReleaseDC(bmDC); здесь еще HWND добавить надо в параметре?

Comment: А Bitmap и HDC один раз можно создать в начале программы потом в цикле отрисовывать через BitBtl а в конце при завершении программы удалить все? Или так в цикле все и писать?

Comment: а картинку делать сразу BitBlt - это как?

Comment: А вы как считаете лучше выводить картинки через BitBlt или StretchDIBits?)

Comment: @helldrg, если не нужно масштабирование, то определенно лучше BitBlt.

Comment: Блин, что то не понимаю, " 
Можно один раз создать, а потом даже менять память, а картинку делать сразу BitBlt"
Если я меняю содержимое буфера, а в цикле у меня только BitBlt, то выводится черный экран

Comment: Какого размера картинка, и какие операции вы с ней делаете. Если очень большая - лучше OpenGL. Если операции простые может проще использывать другие GDI функции, например SetPixel

Comment: Так не получится. Нужно делать SetDIBits при пустом bmDC (делать SelectObject, SetDIBits, SelectObject, BitBlt, или создавать секцию. Я дописал ниже как её создать.

Comment: Я понимаю, что надо Opengl использовать, просто интересно узнать как на GDI это все работает =)
Спасибо большое вам!!! 
Единственное я думал BitBtl будет меньше цп нагружать, а он на пол процента больше нагружает чем StretchDIBits.
А операция только перемещение в одном месте, а так просто вывод и изменение её на другую при наведении
Огромное вас спасибо!!!

Comment: только вместо bits я сразу поставил buffer->memory

Comment: спасибо за анализ, не думал что всё так плохо в винде, я считал что так будет быстрее работать. Могу ещё подкинуть идею SetDIBitsToDevice это аналог StretchDIBits но вроде проще. По идее много времени уходит на преобразование, надо задавать именно тот формат пикселей который задан в системе (16 или 32 бита а не 24), и именно в нем делать изображение - тогда система будет просто копировать данные. Я делал карту через ф-ции 8000x8000 под GDI она перемещалась рывками, а под openGL только на 200MHz было заметно торможение в четверть секунды при перемещении карты мышкой.

Comment: Buffer->Info.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32; вроде 24 нигде не задан у меня
А с SetDIBitsToDevice  как сделать? 
А насчет OpenGl я обязательно на него перейду просто хочется эту тему добить =)