# Подключение POCO dll C++

Tags: c++, dll, poco

Пытаюсь подключить `POCO`-библиотеки. Собрал `dll` проекта для работы с `ZIP`.
Подключение `dll`, в свой проект, произвёл простым добавлением `dll` в решение.

Нашёл пример, в котором говорилось: как вызывать функции из `dll`. Создаётся указатель на функцию и т.д., но в примере, в сигнатуре метода, используются стандартные типы данных. В моём случае в параметры приходят пользовательские типы из `dll`(возможно даже из другой, на основе которой была собрана первая `dll`).

Можно пример подключения `dll` в коде и обращения к её функциям для моего случая?

Пример создания указателя на функцию:

```
typedef void(*LibraryFunction)(std::istream&, const Poco::DateTime&, const Poco::Path&, ZipCommon::CompressionMethod, ZipCommon::CompressionLevel);
```

Параметры с пространством Poco:: и ZipCommon говорят об ошибке: должен быть классом или пространством имён. Я так понимаю потому, что такое пространство не существует в моём проекте и из dll его не видать.

Comment: Предлагаете угадать какие же типы данных в вашем случае? Загрузка DLL и получение адреса функции в ней вообще не требуют знания о типах. Типы нужны чтобы объявить указатель нужного типа, почитайте про указатели на функции.

Comment: Ну а я о чём говорю? Как я могу написать указатель на функцию, если типы параметров для него не видны из dll?

Comment: А как тогда DLL собралась, если она ничего о типах своих аргументов не знает? Что-то вы не так понимаете.

Comment: Ну я похоже правда не понимаю), dll собралась в своём проекте. Далее я её подключил к моему проекту, в котором уже и пытаюсь написать указатель на функцию из dll. Может я не так делаю.

Comment: dll условно всеравно какой тип ваших параметров, лишь бы расположения байт совпадало. Хотите - передаёте структуру, хотите массив. Приведите кусок кода где у вас возникла проблема.

Comment: Вот пример подключения сторонней библиотеки gdi+, и передача ей параметров совсем не таких как она хочет (не таких как в хедерах к GDI+),  через массив http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/557112/17974

Comment: Добавил пример указателя на функцию

Comment: Вам нужно либо 1)подключить хеадер библиотеки Poco, который содержит DateTime, тогда будет совпадение типов, либо 2) использовать анонимные указатели типа void*, но может вам всёравно прийтется подключить библиотеку. 3) если DateTime совпадает с стандартным DateTime, то пишити DateTime& без указания Poco, но если не совпадает вы рискуете получить неправильную работу ПО и Exception. 4) как крайний рабочий вариант, скопировать из библиотеки Poco обьявление DateTime и работать с ним, но тогда проще пункт 1.

Comment: Аналогично с ZipCommon. Поясню, h-файлы используются для декларирования структур и функций, а c/cpp файлы для реализации (сбора в exe или dll). Поэтому вам всёрано нужно сделать типа `#include "poco.h"` и `#include "ZipCommon.h"` файлы я пытаюсь угадать, они могут отличатся.

Comment: Вот я и пытаюсь подключить. ПИ Poco определено в классе Compress.h. Я пишу в своём проекте #include "Compress.h", но он его не видит. Я думаю, что я всё-таки недоподключил dll)

Comment: Проверяйте путь. Может надо `#include "../Compress.h"` или `#include "zip/Compress.h"` внимательно проверьте папки

Comment: Эти исходники лежат отдельно от моего проекта, в моём только dll. Мне и исходники надо добавить? Тогда смысл dll?

Answer (score 1):

Нужно в том cpp или h, где используется **Poco::Zip:Common** добавить *#include< Poco/Zip/ZipCommon.h>*, аналогично поступаете с другими компонентами фреймворка.

В линковке указать библиотеки **PocoFoundation** **PocoZip** 
Далее прописать пути поиска библиотек и хидеров(все зависит от вашей IDE и системы сборки).
В целом эта схема для любой библиотеки или вреймворка будет аналогичной.