# Загрузка png в TImage

Tags: c++builder, radstudio

Пол года назад работал в Rad Studio 10 Seattle. Был у меня класс, который наследовался от `TImage`
В конструкторе я писал:

```
Parent = Owner;
AutoSize = true;
TPicture *pic = new TPicture();
pic->LoadFromFile("Textures/r1.png");
Picture = pic;
```

И загружался png файл, и всё работало нормально
Сейчас, когда я пишу такой же код, мне пишет `Bitmap image is not valid`
Почему раньше получалось, а сейчас нет?
P.S. Сейчас у меня Rad Studio 10 Berlin

Comment: У png есть несколько методов(способов) сжатия, 1)может быть теперь у вас не тот метод который был в случае когда работало. 2)Может библиотека теперь не поддерживает png.

Comment: Если у вас windows платформа попробуйте  [так](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/556781/17974)

Comment: @nick_n_a судя по всему проблема не в изображении. Если кинуть TImage на форму и в Picture выбрать мою картинку, то всё нормально

Comment: Выбрать картинку в designer-е - там для этого отдельная design-time библиотека (та которая только в режиме разработки работает), которая может его перекодировать как нужно самому TPicture.