# Как на C++ получить в буфер сжатый JPEG из структуры VIDEOHDR?

Tags: c++, jpeg, gdi+

Делаю кадр с камеры средствами avicap32... В CALLBACK-функции захвата кадра получаю указатель на структуру `VIDEOHDR`. Теперь нужно взять `lpVHDR->lpData` и как-то сделать из него буфер со сжатым JPEG-ом.

Когда я делал захват кадра в браузере средствами JS (getUserMedia), то из canvas'а получался base64-jpeg размером ~13 Кб (при сжатии 50% при разрешении 320x240). Надо как-то сделать такое сжатие на C++, так как текущий сырой бинарник весит ~200 Кб, что многовато для поставленных задач.

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать JPEG из `lpVHDR->lpData` и сжать его? Желательно, конечно, без сторонних библиотек (средствами GDI+ наверно), но если без них никак - буду разбираться. Только дайте направление пожалуйста ))

PS: сохранять файл не надо, так как "общение" с жёстким диском скажется на скорости работы приложения. JPEG нужен в буфере для последующей отправки на сервер.

Инициализация формата и разрешения после вызова `capDriverConnect`:

```
capGetVideoFormat(HStream, &BitmapInfo, sizeof(BitmapInfo));
BitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biWidth = 320;
BitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight = 240;
BitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biCompression = 0x32595559;
BitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage = 153600;
capSetVideoFormat(HStream, &BitmapInfo, sizeof(BitmapInfo));
```

Если устанавливать `BI_JPEG` в `biCompression`, то `capSetVideoFormat` возвращает `FALSE` почему-то.

Comment: [Вот](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/557112/17974) пример как загрузить картинку используя GDI+, если указатель содержит валидный JPG. Если он содержит кусок JPG (Например сами сжатые данные без шапки) то прийдётся сначала сделать memory-jpg с JFIF сигнатурой, а потом вызывать `GdipCreateBitmapFromStream`.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо. Но что значит "валидный JPG"? Я дописал код битмап-хедера, там только YUY2 устанавливается. Это не помешает?

Comment: Валидный - имеется ввиду такой "пакет" байт, который если сохранить на диск как 1.jpg и открыть - то будет видно картинку. Пакет обычно содержит  JFIF (4A 46 49 46)-сигнатуру.

Comment: Про base64 я писал для сравнения. Мне нужно из VIDEOHDR получить jpeg такого размера. Сейчас, если делать для теста capFileSaveDIB(HStream, "1.jpg");, то файл будет размером 230 кб, а в lpData VIDEOHDR всего 150 кб данных, то есть там что-то сырое-сырое. Вот это сырое можно как-то привести к JPEG-у через GDI+?

Comment: Я не вижу что у вас в  lpData. Три варианта. 1. Простейший, это bitmap или другой формат который видит GDI+ - просто грузим в GDI, может даже ваш HStream позицируем в 0 и отправляем в GdipCreateBitmapFromStream. 2. это просто набор байт RGB - преобразуем в bitmap и грузим в GDI либо ф-ция `GdipCreateBitmapFromScan0`. 3. Если это сжатый поток - ищем как расжать  и делаем 1 или 2. Ссылка на [msdn GDI+](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms533971%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: В GDI+ bitmap  наследует image, у іmage есть [save](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms535406%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), где можно указать jpg формат - но это уже когда получилось загрузить в GDI+

Comment: Спасибо, за развёрнутые ответы - натолкнули на мысль )) ! Поток у меня в YUY2 получается (другой формат не ставится почему-то). Следовательно, буду искать как "YUY2 to JPEG GDI+"

Comment: Врядли. Вам проще почитать про  YUY2  и преобразовать в RGB циклом, а там уже получив практически bmp сжать как нужно.

Comment: Спасибо! Буду пробовать...

Comment: Чем вызвана приверженность к средствам GDI+ ?

Comment: Отсутствием необходимости использовать сторонние библиотеки, с которыми будет ещё больше головной боли - собрать их для MinGW, например, слинковать всё статически, что раздует exe до неприличия... Или есть ещё "родные" варианты кроме GDI+?

Comment: А почему не удаётся установить формат с biCompression =  BI_BITFIELDS (или BI_RGB)? Может что-то ещё надо изменить в структуре BITMAPINFOHEADER?