# Как вставить картинку с альфа каналом в Photoshop при помощи WinApi?

Tags: winapi, photoshop, clipboard

Я хочу вставить картинку с альфа каналом в Photoshop при помощи WinApi. Я попытался вставить картинку в формате PNG. Для этого я использовал методы `Clipboard`'a. А именно зарегистрировал формат с именем "PNG" и далее сохранил данные в клипбоард. Данная процедура работает для Gimp и MSOffice 2007. Но вот фотошоп никак не может распознать этот формат. Как можно по-другому вставить картинку в Photoshop?

Comment: 1. Копируем аналогичный случай в фотошопе, закрываем фотошоп. Открываем вставляем. Если получилось то - 2. Открываем при помощи clipboard на API буфер обмена, и смотрим какие форматы поддерживает фотошоп (имеется ввижу CF_TEXT CF_BITMAP и прочие). Так же можно IDA или другм дизассемблером посмотреть какие у него стоят `RegisterClipboardFormat` (функция даёт айдишки для нестандартных CF_xxx)

Comment: То есть просто посмотреть в каких форматах экспортирует фотошоп картинки?

Comment: Да, но я не встречал хорошего "тестора" clibpboard.  А clibpboard и Drag&Drop передаёт данные в "мультиформате", и приложение принимающее этот "мультиформат" выбирает один тот формат, который она умеет расшифровать на своё усмотрение.

Comment: @nick_n_a, я уже попробовал и нашел форматы (оказывается photoshop не экспортирует png явно). Теперь пытаюсь засунуть в него битмэп

Comment: Вот я нашёл "шпион" форматов http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/clipboard/externallinks/article.php/c9155/Clipboard-Viewer.htm там в папке release архива exe-шник

Comment: @nick_n_a, воу, спасибо. я использовал другую программу - (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15689541/win32-clipboard-and-alpha-channel-images)

Comment: Да, похоже вам прийдётся использовать CF_DIB. Посмотрите сюда, может отсюда http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/556781/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%A1-win можно CF_DIB вьесто CF_BITMAP достать ?  В вопросе прийдётся заменить CF_BITMAP на CF_DIB и немного подколдовать.

Comment: @nick_n_a, по сути об этом можно не сильно переживать - os windows умеет автоматически конвертировать форматы друг в друга. Думаю пока CF_DIB пробовать

Comment: Смотря какой интефейс на WINAPI вы используете для копирования. Если вы заносите SetClipboard как CF_BITMAP то точно получите лажу.

Comment: Вы хотите из памяти или локальный файл скопировать? У вас не указан язык, вы на с++ c# или Delphi?

Comment: @nick_n_a, я на с++, но не думаю что это принципиально (хотя наверное для c# уже это все реализовано)

Comment: Я попробовал через OLE вытащить CF_DIF, мне OLE ответила что не поддерживает.