# Как подключить jpg картинку в API

Tags: c++, winapi, jpeg

Пробую через olectl.h- почему не получается.Вот код.

```
static TCHAR szWindowClass[] = _T("winClass");
static TCHAR szTitle[] = _T("Pattern");

HINSTANCE hInst;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,LPSTR lpCmdLine,int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInstance, (LPCSTR)IDI_ICON1);
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(hInstance, (LPCSTR)IDC_CURSOR6);
    wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wcex.lpszClassName = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm = LoadIcon(hInstance, (LPCSTR)IDI_ICON1);

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wcex))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,_T("Call to RegisterClassEx failed!"),_T("Win32 Guided Tour"),NULL);

        return 1;
    }

    hInst = hInstance; // Store instance handle in our global variable

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindow(szWindowClass,szTitle,WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW|WS_VISIBLE,CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,800, 300,NULL,NULL,  hInstance,NULL);

    if (!hWnd)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,_T("Call to CreateWindow failed!"),_T("Win32 Guided Tour"), NULL);

        return 1;
    }


    /*ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);*/

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return (int)msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    HDC hDC;

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0); 
        break;
    /*case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        hDC = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        BITMAP bm;
        HDC hdcMem;
        HBITMAP back = LoadBitmap(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP3));
        hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hDC);
        SelectObject(hdcMem, back);
        GetObject(back, sizeof(BITMAP), (LPVOID)&bm);
        RECT r;
        GetClientRect(hWnd, &r);
        if (!bm.bmWidth || !bm.bmHeight)
            return 0;
        int w = r.right - r.left,
            h = r.bottom - r.top,
            bw = bm.bmWidth,
            bh = bm.bmHeight;
        StretchBlt(hDC, r.left, r.top, r.right, r.bottom, hdcMem, 0, 0, bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight, SRCCOPY);
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    }*/
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}

HRESULT Load(LPCTSTR szFile)
{
    CComPtr <IStream> Stream;

    // Load the file to a memory stream
    HRESULT hr = FileToStream(szFile, &Stream);

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        // Decode the picture
        hr = ::OleLoadPicture(
            Stream,            // [in] Pointer to the stream that contains picture's data
            0,                    // [in] Number of bytes read from the stream (0 == entire)
            true,                // [in] Loose original format if true
            IID_IPicture,        // [in] Requested interface
            (void**)&m_pPicture // [out] IPictire object on success
        );
    }

    return hr;
}

HRESULT DrawImg(HDC hdc, const RECT& rcBounds)
{
    if (m_pPicture)
    {

        // Get the width and the height of the picture
        long hmWidth = 0, hmHeight = 0;
        m_pPicture->get_Width(&hmWidth);
        m_pPicture->get_Height(&hmHeight);

        // Convert himetric to pixels
        int nWidth = MulDiv(hmWidth, ::GetDeviceCaps(hdc, LOGPIXELSX), HIMETRIC_INCH);
        int nHeight = MulDiv(hmHeight, ::GetDeviceCaps(hdc, LOGPIXELSY), HIMETRIC_INCH);

        // Display the picture using IPicture::Render
        return m_pPicture->Render(
            hdc,                            // [in] Handle of device context on which to render the image
            rcBounds.left,                    // [in] Horizontal position of image in hdc
            rcBounds.top,                    // [in] Vertical position of image in hdc
            rcBounds.right - rcBounds.left,    // [in] Horizontal dimension of destination rectangle
            rcBounds.bottom - rcBounds.top, // [in] Vertical dimension of destination rectangle
            0,                                // [in] Horizontal offset in source picture
            hmHeight,                        // [in] Vertical offset in source picture
            hmWidth,                        // [in] Amount to copy horizontally in source picture
            -hmHeight,                        // [in] Amount to copy vertically in source picture
            &rcBounds                        // [in, optional] Pointer to position of destination for a metafile hdc
        );
    }

    return E_UNEXPECTED;
}

`
```

Comment: `OleLoadPicture` поддерживает только файлы bmp, ico и wmf. Лучше будет использовать [WIC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719655(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Используйте OleCreateFromFile например как тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/556781/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bc%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%a1-win он поддерживает jpg и png дополнительно.

Comment: По той же ссылке - можно найти как GDI+ задействовать.