# Интерфейс IStream в WinApi (или как вывести картинку в окно через GDI+)

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi+

Подскажите пожалуйста, если кто знает, что физически делает этот интерфейс Istream в WinApi.
Вот есть такой код для примера:

```
 char my_char[] = {1,-1,0,8,120,90};   //Условно это бинарник к примеру bmp файла.

    IStream* my_stream1;
    my_stream1 = SHCreateMemStream((const BYTE*)my_char, 6);
    Gdiplus::Image* my_image1 = Gdiplus::Image::FromStream(my_stream1);
```

Моя цель отобразить просто в окне графический файл с помощью GDI+, но, так как обьект Gdiplus::Image может принимать буфер данных с картинкой только из файла или из потока, то для того, чтобы скормить мой буфер my_char объекту Gdiplus::Image - нужно использовать IStream и SHCreateMemStream.

Можно конечно, просто забить и использовать их, как черный ящик, так как и так все работает, но хотелось бы хотя бы примерно понять, что делают с моим буфером my_char - IStream и SHCreateMemStream?

Почему блин Microsoft не сделал функцию или метод, который бы просто принимал указатель на буфер, нафига они сделали вот через эти Istream`ы.

Comment: Массив байтов преобразуется в стрим. Всё.

Comment: Alexander Petrov, а зачем ? Мне просто интересно почему нельзя было сделать просто передачу массива и пусть там уже внутри преобразовывалось в стримы и тому подобное.

Comment: Угу, и имя файла пусть принимает, и http-адрес, и подсоединение к БД...

Comment: Alexander Petrov, вроде понял, но к примеру есть метод Gdiplus::Image::FromFile - который принимает имя файла :)   Ну могли бы для удобства еще один метод допилить с буффером...

Comment: В массиве байтов может быть что угодно. Картинка, текст, видео, аудио. В любом формате. Когда используется IStream, сразу становится ясно, что этот набор байтов должен быть в формате стрима.

Comment: Всё предусмотреть невозможно.

Comment: Может вам это надо? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/556781/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bc%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%a1-win/557112#557112

Answer (score 0):

Единственное, что делает интерфейс `Istream` - является интерфейсом. Т.е. предоставляет возможность получать последовательность байт независимо от их источника, будь то один буфер в памяти (как в вопросе), или пакеты с данными, принятыми по сети, или пакеты с данными из COM порта, или разжимаемый на лету архив, или еще что. Похожую роль в стандартной библиотеке выполняет интерфейс `istream` например.